# Better dialog shadows in YUI 2?

Tags: dialog, yui, javascript-framework, css-sprites, dropshadow

Here's a tricky one: has anybody seen a YUI dialog/panel implementation with nice OS X style shadows around the dialog, instead of the blocky shadow that is implemented by default with the "underlay" element?

[image: This kind of shadow]

You can see this type of shadow on Amazon.com popup windows. It requires quite a bit of PNGs but looks very nice.

I'm thinking of inserting extra DIVs or replacing the .underlay element, and hook into the dialog size event to adapt the dimensions. The latter would be required because YUI uses some CSS trickery to make the underlay element "snap" to the dialog dimensions with CSS only in modern browsers, and uses a manual dimension update for IE.

EDIT: Just checked YUI 3. The Panel widget is not available yet, only the Container and it's still beta. So I'm looking at solving this in YUI 2.

PS: Oh I guess I could include the PNG shadow as part of the Panel's header, body and footer (hd, bd, ft), as an extra padding. And use a css rule to hide YUI's underlay. Hmmmmmm I just wish I didn't have to do this because it changes calculations for the draggable area, it's not a great way to do it.

Comment: Nice one (+1) Let me know if you has solved your requirement

Comment: I followed the advice in another question and used a CSS 3 shadow, which work in pretty much every browser except IE (using the vendor specific rules). IE users will not see a shadow (perhaps IE9 will?) but that doesn't prevent them from using the features ("progressive degradation"). Since IE traffic on this web app is only 8%, that's perfectly acceptable to me. I may still look at using my custom PNG shadow later, as the CSS3 box shadow doesn't look great on the corners.

Comment: PS: if your app can live with fixed-size dialogs then the matter is very simple (in theory, haven't tried): you may simply style the underlay to use a png shadow of the proper size, and also adapt the styles of the "SAM" skin (yui-skin-sam) to have more legroom in the underlay padding on the sides and bottom. If you use popups mostly for confirmation or error messages for example, you could set the dialog to 400x200 pixels for example, and the shadow PNG accordingly. Center the text to deal with the whitespace. This would be fine.